# Puppeteer Select Method Ignores Disabled Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I have a disabled select element in an html file which I would like to check using puppeteer that it is in fact disabled. Unfortunately the `page.select` method seems to ignore the lock on the field element. Here is a stripped down example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <select id='dropdown' disabled>
      <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now if I open this index.html I cannot change the select as expected but when interfacing with puppeteer using the `page.select` method I can.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch( { headless: false} );
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const content = fs.readFileSync('./index.html', 'utf8');
  await page.setContent(content);
  await page.select('#dropdown', 'op2');
})();
```

Now if I understand the puppeteer documentation correctly, then this should not result in the select option changing, but never the less it does. Am I missing something, or do I need to do something else in order to check that the element is locked.

Comment: The `disabled` option never stops JavaScript from interacting with an element; it's purely blocking end-users from interacting with it. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-disabled): "*This Boolean attribute indicates that the user cannot interact with the control.*"

Comment: Is there a similar puppeteer method which would instead go through the selection like a user would? Something akin to `page.type` for text fields?

Comment: No - if you want to respect the `disabled` attribute from the JavaScript execution environment, you’ll have to check if the attribute is present yourself beforehand.

Comment: You could use `page.evaluate` and interact using the browser engine rather than puppeteers exposed methods, if that is advantageous.

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch That will still not prevent the field from being set - the browser’s JavaScript engine doesn’t respect the `disabled` attribute - again, it’s only for end users that it’s enforced for. Can you link a source that says otherwise?

Comment: ah I misunderstood, I was under the impression he was not able to change it with puppeteer's methods.